# Splinter saves bodiless html

Tags: python, screen-scraping, splinter

I am using the `splinter 0.7.3` module in `python 2.7.2` on a Linux platform to scrape a directory listing on a website using the default Firefox browser.

This is the snippet of code that iterates through the paginated web listing by clicking the 'Next' link in the html.

```
    links = True
    i = 0
    while links:
        with open('html/register_%03d.html' % i, 'w') as f:
            f.write(browser.html.encode('utf-8'))
        links = browser.find_link_by_text('Next')
        print 'links:', links
        if links:
            links[0].click()
        i += 1
```

I know that the links are working, as I am seeing output that looks like this:

```
links: [<splinter.driver.webdriver.WebDriverElement object at 0x2e6da10>, <splinter.driver.webdriver.WebDriverElement object at 0x2e6d710>]
links: [<splinter.driver.webdriver.WebDriverElement object at 0x2e6d5d0>, <splinter.driver.webdriver.WebDriverElement object at 0x2e6d950>]
links: [<splinter.driver.webdriver.WebDriverElement object at 0x2e6d710>, <splinter.driver.webdriver.WebDriverElement object at 0x2e6dcd0>]
links: []
```

When the html is saved at each page using `f.write(browser.html.encode('utf-8'))` it works fine for the first page. On subsequent pages, although I can see the pages rendered in Firefox, either the `html/regiser_...html` file is empty or the body tag is missing like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#" class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"  lang="en-gb"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#" class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"  lang="en-gb"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#" class="no-js lt-ie9"  lang="en-gb"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!-->
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en-gb" class="no-js" prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#"><!--<![endif]--><head>
        <meta content="IE=edge,chrome=1" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" />    
    ...
  </style>
  <script src="/media/com_magebridge/js/frototype.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script></head></html>
```

Is this a known feature of saving html from splinter? Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: I've just tried upgrading my Mint Lisa's version of Firefox from 7.0.1 to 20.0 . The problem still persists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It really looks like a timing issue - *you are getting the page source when the page is not fully loaded*. There are several ways to tackle the issue:

- wait for the `body` [to be present](http://splinter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/driver-and-element-api.html#splinter.driver.DriverAPI.is_element_present_by_tag):

  ```
  browser.is_element_present_by_tag("body", wait_time=5)
  ```
- increase the [page load timeout](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.set_page_load_timeout) - put this right after you initialize the `browser` object:

  ```
  browser.driver.set_page_load_timeout(10)  # 10 seconds
  ```

Comment: Just want to confirm that you received Bounty. I'm on holiday & doing this through my phone.

Comment: @ChrisGuest thanks, got the bounty. Hope the answer helped.